# Switch Chrome interface between smartphone mode and tablet mode

Tags: chrome-for-android

I want to change the interface of Chrome on my Mediapad T2 7.0 Pro (PLE-701L). Now it looks like the smartphone version (picture at right side):

[image]

But I want to change the interface to tablet mode (picture at left).
As I know there is a special command for switching the interface.

Config:

- Tablet: Mediapad T2 7.0 Pro (PLE-701L)
- Resolution: 1200x1920
- OS: Lolipop (5.1.1)
- UI: EMUI 3.1
- Chrome: 66.0.3359.158
- Root: doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change the DPI of your phone to accomplish it. But, the change will affect the whole system not just Chrome and may not be retained after a restart due to your device not been rooted.

`adb shell wm density 600` (When I tested, 600 was the value that enabled the change of interface in Chrome).

For those who have newer version of Android, the DPI can be changed by going to Settings -> System -> Developer Option -> Smallest width.

Chrome's interface will change from phone to tablet.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: didnt work for me. Even on 700, still Phone-mode in Chrome :(

Comment: I can confirm that for Android 7 on my TAB S2, that changing: Settings -> Developer Options -> Minimum Width, to anything below 600 activates "phone" mode. Anything equal to or above 600 activates "tablet" mode. Setting sticks between reboots.

Comment: I started with minimum width 600, it did activate tablet mode for Google Chrome on my Google pixel 7. It made the font smaller than I liked So I started messing with the minimum width... As info, the default setting was 411... The closest I was able to get and still have tablet mode in Google Chrome is 476. Thank you guys so much!